# Removing Windows 10 'Unwanted' Apps

Tags: windows

I want to set it so that the Windows 10 tiles for things like Candy Crush do not appear for users logging in to a machine. This is on a fresh 1909 install.

I understand that these apps aren't installed as such, I just want to hide that tile.

information here - https://blog.danic.net/how-windows-10-pro-installs-unwanted-apps-candy-crush-and-how-you-stop-it/ suggests editing registry keys at

HKU\Default_User\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager

However I don't have this 'ContentDeliveryManager' folder. I'm finding that other similar solutions have similar results - I don't have the same registry keys!

Does anyone have any advice?